# RedirectToAction Returning 301

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-5

Why does `RedirectToAction()` return an HTTP 301 in Chrome and 302 in incognito mode?
Isn't it meant to always return 302?

I tested `RedirectToActionPermanent()` and it returns 301 in normal and incognito mode as expected.

Comment: Are you sure. Server will have no idea whether browser is incognito or not.

Comment: It always returns 302. My guess is that at some point in the past you were playing around and used `RedirectToActionPermanent`? In which case, the browser has cached that (which is understandable - you told it it was **permanent**).

Comment: @mjwills you're right. I did initially play around with RedirectToActionPermanent